# Acm style bibliography is shortening 3rd author

Tags: bibliographies

I have the following entry in my bibliography :

```
@article{szymanski,
author={Zbigniew Szymański, Stanisław Jankowski, Jan Szczyrek},
title="Reconstruction of environment model by using radar vector field histograms",
journal="Photonics Applications in Astronomy, Communications, Industry, and High-Energy Physics Experiments",
volume= "8454",
issue = "4",
pages= "1-8",
year="2012"
}
```

When I put a reference to this article I get in the references section this :

[image]

How do I prevent the shortening of 3rd author ?

( I can provide what am I using - whether it is Bibtex or Biblatex or anything - but how can I check it?)

Comment: You should (must, actually) use `and` as the separator between authors' full names. This is true for both BibTeX and biblatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your authors:

```
Zbigniew Szymański, Stanisław Jankowski, Jan Szczyrek
```

should be:

```
Szymański, Zbigniew and Jankowski, Stanisław and Szczyrek, Jan
```

Comment: Why did you change the ordering from `FirstName SurName` to  `SurName, FirstName`?

Comment: This is standard BibTeX format - this page has more details: http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-23.html